# Define operator for built-in and class instance

Tags: python

In Python you can override an operation for your class (say, addition) by defining `__add__`. This will make it possible add class instance with other values/instances, but you can't add built-ins to instances:

```
foo = Foo()
bar = foo + 6 # Works
bar = 6 + foo # TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'Foo'
```

Is there any way to make enable this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to define the method [`__radd__(self, other)`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__radd__) to override the operator `+` when your instance is on the right side.

Comment: Note that Python will still attempt to call `__add__()`, catch the exception, and *then* look for `__radd__()`.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot override the + operator for integers. What you should do is to override the `__radd__(self, other)` function *in the Foo class only*. The `self` variable references a `Foo` instance, not an integer, and the `other` variable references the object on the **left** side of the + operator. When `bar = 6 + foo` is evaluated, the attempt to evaluate `6.__add__(foo)` fails and then Python tries `foo.__radd__(6)` (reverse `__add__`). If you override `__radd__` inside `Foo`, the reverse `__add__` succeeds, and the evaluation of `6 + foo` is the result of `foo.__radd__(6)`.

```
def __radd__(self, other):
   return self + other
```

Comment: Very informative answer. I only have a small correction. You write *the `other` variable references the object on the right side* but it should be *on the **left** side*.

Comment: @halex: Thank you for the correction. I've definitely intended [your other right](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=your%20other%20right).